# Create javascript object based on select

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `<select>` tag with several values in my html.
I also have a constructor function in javascript.
The problem I'm trying to solve is creating js objects based on selected value. Right now I have a solution with if statements, which calls a constructor function with parameters based on select value. It works fine when there are not much values in select. But if there are many values, this way seems to be extremely inefficient. Is there a more efficient way to do this, without the if statements?

Here is a fiddle: 
https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/NjvOOJ

```
function Human(lastName, firstName, age){
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.age = age;

  return this;
}

function createHumanObj(e){

    var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
    var selctedHuman = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    if(selctedHuman == 'john'){
        var currentHuman = new Human('John', 'Dalton', 28)
    }
    if(selctedHuman == 'tony'){
        var currentHuman = new Human('Anthony', 'Stark', 50)
    }

    return currentHuman;
}
```

Comment: How do you knpw that `john` has the surname `Dalton` and age `28`? Same for other humans.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to prepopulate the HTML, you could populate the select options with custom attributes and pick them within your JS like the below:

```js
function createHumanObj(e){
  
var e = document.getElementById("mySelect"),
    selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex],
    firstname = selected.value,
    lastname = selected.getAttribute("data-lastname");

var currentHuman = new Human(firstname, lastname, 28);

return currentHuman;
}
```

```html
<select>
 <option value="John" data-lastname="Dalton"></option>
 <option value="Anthony" data-lastname="Start"></option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating the objects when they are selected, since they are always the same (I guess?) why not store them in a "map"? Like this:

```js
var exampleJson = '{"john":{"lastName":"John","firstName":"Dalton","age":28},"tony":{"lastName":"Anthony","firstName":"Stark","age":50}}';
// the json can come from a webservice, for example

var humans = JSON.parse(exampleJson);

function createHumanObj() {

  var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
  var selectedHuman = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  return humans[selectedHuman];
}

function showHumanProps() {
  var log = document.getElementById("log");
  var currentHuman = createHumanObj();
  log.innerHTML = currentHuman.firstName + " " + currentHuman.lastName + " " + currentHuman.age; 
}

var btn = document.getElementById("btn");

btn.addEventListener('click', showHumanProps);
```

```html
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="john">john</option>
  <option value="tony">tony</option>
 </select><br><br>
 <button id="btn">Show human props</button><br><br>
 <div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### To handle duplicate first names or last names.

pre-create humans and store them with index.

```
var humans = {
  0: new Human('John', 'Dalton', 28),
  1: new Human('Anthony', 'Stark', 50),
  //...
};
```

and

`var human = humans[e.selectedIndex];`

Answer (score 0):

Can try this also-

```js
function Human(userData){
      this.lastName = userData.lastName;
      this.firstName = userData.firstName;
      this.age = userData.age;
     }

    function createHumanObj(e){      
     var e = document.getElementById("mySelect");
     var selctedHuman = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
        var data= {
              "john": {
                  "firstName": "John",
                  "lastName": "Dalton",
                  "age": 28
              },
              "tony": {
                  "firstName": "Anthony",
                  "lastName": "Stark",
                  "age": 50
              }
         };
      
     return new Human(data[selctedHuman]);
    }

    (function(){
      var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      addEventListener('click', showHumanProps);          
      function showHumanProps(){
        var log = document.getElementById("log");
        var currentHuman = createHumanObj();
        log.innerHTML = currentHuman.firstName + " " + currentHuman.lastName + " " + currentHuman.age; 
      }
    })();
```

```css
select, button, #log{
      display: block;
      margin: 10px auto;
      font-size: 25px;
      text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
<select name="mySelect" id="mySelect">
  <option value="john">John</option>
  <option value="tony">Tony</option>
</select>

<button id="btn">Show human props</button>

<div id="log"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

In a situation where 1 value needs to be selected from a range of discrete values I use a switch statement. For your example I would use this for the 'createHumanObj' function:

```
function createHumanObj(e){
  var selectedHuman = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

  switch(selectedHuman) {
    case 'John':
      return new Human('John', 'Dalton', 28)

    case 'Tony':
      return new Human('Anthony', 'Stark', 50)

    default:
      console.log('Unknown human')
  }
}
```

Comment: This is no better than the `if...else` solution.